# Using CData to migrate data from SQL Server to MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, cdata

I am trying to migrate a table called `table1` in SQL Server with the following details:

| username | account_name | description | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nvarchar(255) | nvarchar(255) | nvarchar(255) | date |
| primary_key |  |  |  |

I am using CData to migrate this table to my MariaDB database. If anyone here is familiar with CData, the command I am using to migrate the table is `REPLICATE [dbo].[table1]`. When I run the code in CData, I am getting an error stating: `BLOB/TEXT column 'username' used in key specification without key length (1170)`. I don't understand this error because I do not have a BLOB/TEXT column in my table anywhere. When migrating the data to MariaDB, `nvarchar` should convert to `varchar` (which it has done for my other tables so not sure why this is causing an issue here). Is it because it's the primary key? I can't delete the PK on this table, I need it there so I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Comment: What is "CData" in this context? The `cdata` tag you've used refers to XML `<![[CDATA` which I assume is not what you're referring to.

Comment: https://www.cdata.com/sync/ is what i am referring to

Comment: Definitely seems like it is making username a blob or text, not a varchar.  Does cdata give you a way to make it use a varchar(255)?

Comment: Even that may not work; what version of mariadb are you using (show output of `select version();`)

Comment: yes the table mapping shows "varchar" as the destination table's column datatype so its clearly doing it. i think its converting it to TEXT/BLOB bc nvarchar(255) is too big a number to convert to varchar so it's trying to make it a text?

Comment: my mariaDB version is 10.5.17

Comment: You can have much longer varchar than that nowadays.  Can you do `show create table table1;` in mariadb?

Comment: CREATE TABLE table1 (
 username nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 account_name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 description nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 change_date date NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK__table1__9383FHKS922GWG1 PRIMARY KEY (table1)
);

That code is for the table in SQL Server. There is no table in MariaDB that is replicated yet because of the error I am getting for the BLOB/TEXT column I described above